# How do I display the data in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Temperature=37 , humidity = 60 //data from api 
String read =
    "humblehacks.xyz/Server.php?patient=Yassen%20Mohamed&request=REQUEST_DATA_DAWNLOAD";
http.Response jread = await http.get(Uri.parse(read));
if (jread.statusCode == 200) {
  var body = jread.body;
```

I am using api to get data , but not by json or xml just string ,
How do I show the data , I can't use Jsondecode because ABI is not Json
i want to display 37 and 60 in app , how can i display it I want full code

Comment: More details are needed. Here is some information on [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Output widgets like text should suffice

```
 Text(37.toString()), // Simple value
 Text("Temperature $val"), //String and variable
 Text("Temperature ${temp.val}"),//String and map item
```